# Class already defined when trying to compile

Tags: java

I wrote this code, but it wont compile because class temperature says it is already defined.

#### Error message:

> The type temperature is already defined

How to fix it?

---

#### Code

```
package exercise11;

public class working {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        temperature freezing = new temperature(32, 0, 0);
        temperature boiling = new temperature(212, 100, 33);
        temperature human = new temperature(98.6, 37, 12.21);

        System.out.println("water freezes at " + freezing.getFahrenheit() + " Fahrenheit, " + freezing.getCelsius() +
                                   " Celisus, and " + freezing.getNewton() + " Newton");
        System.out.println("water boils at " + boiling.getFahrenheit() + " Fahrenheit, " + boiling.getCelsius() +
                                   " Celisus, and " + boiling.getNewton() + " Newton");
        System.out.println("human body temperature is " + human.getFahrenheit() + " Fahrenheit, " + human.getCelsius() +
                                   " Celisus, and " + human.getNewton() + " Newton");

    }

}

class temperature {

    public temperature(double f, double b, double h) {
    }

    double Fahrenheit;
    double Celsius;
    double Newton;

    public void setTemp(double Fahrenheit, double Celsius, double Newton) {
        setFahrenheit(Fahrenheit);
        setCelsius(Celsius);
        setNewton(Newton);
    }

    public double getNewton() {
        return Newton;
    }

    public double getCelsius() {
        return Celsius;
    }

    public double getFahrenheit() {
        return Fahrenheit;
    }

    public void setFahrenheit(double Fahrenheittemp) {
        Fahrenheit = Fahrenheittemp;
    }

    public void setCelsius(double Celsiustemp) {
        Celsius = Celsiustemp;
    }

    public void setNewton(double Newtontemp) {
        Newton = Newtontemp;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have another class called `temperature`?

Comment: Please use spaces rather than tabs on Stack Overflow, and edit your post so that the code is properly indented. Read the formatting help if you aren't sure how to do that. Then please tell us *exactly* where you're seeing the error, and how you're compiling.

Comment: It's good practice to use capitalized names for classes. So for example: Temperature instead of temperature.

Comment: Yes, make sure your class name and package name is unique.

Comment: *"The type temperature is already defined"* I do not think your compiler/IDE is wrong. First change the name of the class `temperature`, make this work and then start looking at the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working for me. You may want to assign Fahrenheit, Celsius, and Newton in your constructor, though:

```
public class working {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        temperature freezing = new temperature(32,0,0);
        temperature boiling = new temperature(212,100,33);
        temperature human = new temperature(98.6,37,12.21);

        System.out.println("water freezes at " + freezing.getFahrenheit() + " Fahrenheit, " + freezing.getCelsius() + " Celisus, and " + freezing.getNewton() + " Newton");
        System.out.println("water boils at " + boiling.getFahrenheit() + " Fahrenheit, " + boiling.getCelsius() + " Celisus, and " + boiling.getNewton() + " Newton");
        System.out.println("human body temperature is " + human.getFahrenheit() + " Fahrenheit, " + human.getCelsius() + " Celisus, and " + human.getNewton() + " Newton");

    }
} 

class temperature {
    public temperature (double f, double b, double h) {
        Fahrenheit = f; // <==== ADD?
        Celsius = b; // <==== ADD?
        Newton = h; // <==== ADD?
    }
    double Fahrenheit;
    double Celsius;
    double Newton;
    public void setTemp(double Fahrenheit, double Celsius, double Newton){
        setFahrenheit(Fahrenheit);
        setCelsius(Celsius);
        setNewton(Newton);
    }

    public double getNewton() {
        return Newton;
    }
    public double getCelsius() {
        return Celsius;
    }
    public double getFahrenheit() {
        return Fahrenheit;
    }
    public void setFahrenheit(double Fahrenheittemp){
        Fahrenheit = Fahrenheittemp;
    }
    public void setCelsius(double Celsiustemp){
        Celsius = Celsiustemp;
    }
    public void setNewton(double Newtontemp){
        Newton = Newtontemp;
    }
}
```

Comment: how did you get yours to work? I tryed your changes and I still get the same error

Comment: Are you saving it in one file called working.java? Make sure all your parentheses are matched up.

Comment: That will obviously work for you since you don't have any additional `temperature` class which blocks your compilation like in case of OP so this doesn't solve anything. Also please read [are-works-for-me-answers-valid](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118992/are-works-for-me-answers-valid)

Comment: I don't have another temperature class defined in my package. So check if you have a duplicate one in yours (as others have stated).

Answer (score 1):

Probably have temperature defined more than once.

Just change the name of your class from "temperature" to "Temperature" or somethings else. Dont forget the constructor and the places you use it etc.

Answer (score 0):

If this is all in one file, it is probably not the only file being compiled.

Check the other files to see if you have defined the temperature class twice.

--- as an aside, a comment on your design ---

If you have been introduced to polymorphisim, realize that a Temperature is a generalization of the specific measurements systems Fahrenheit, Celsius, and Newton.

So one might be tempted to create a Temperature interface

```
public interface Temperature {
  public double getNewton();
  public double getCelsius();
  public double getFarenheit();
}
```

with three implementing classes

```
public class Netwon implements Temperature {

  private double temp;

  public Newton(double value) {
    this.temp = value;
  }

  public double getNewton() {
    return temp;
  }

  public double getCelsius() {
    return (3*temp);
  }

  public double getFarenheit() {
    return (getCelsius() * 9/5) + 32;
  }
}
```

with two other implementations for each other kind of temperature.  This has the desirable effect of not burdening future-you (and others) of having to calculate by hand the three correct matching values.  Instead you just do

```
public Temperature temp = new Celsius(100);
System.out.println(String.valueOf(temp.getFarenheit());
```

Comment: ps. don't assume the Newton temperature conversions are correct, I just took a guess at them from the input values.

Comment: pps. Learn quickly how to put each class and interface into it's own file, it makes defining a class twice much harder to do without noticing it immediately.